# When performing post via ajax, Bad Request is returned in IE 11

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm using a jquery to make an $.ajax request. It works fine in chrome/firefox and other browsers.Here is my code it's working on other browsers perfectly but not in IE. Please tel me were is wrong.

```
$("#awards-form").on('submit',(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var formData = new FormData(this);

    //var formData = $(this).serialize();

    console.log(formData);

    jQuery.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url: base_url+"xxxxxx",
        data: formData,
        cache:false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success:function(data){
            $("#awardsList").append(data);
            $(".simpleFilePreview").removeClass("picAfterUpload");
        },
        error: function(data){
            $(".simpleFilePreview").removeClass("picAfterUpload");
        }
    });
}));
```

Comment: This looks ok to me. Try debugging the data sent on server side

Comment: FormData in IE is only supported from IE10 so this should work in IE11, without sounding patronising, are you sure your using 11?

Comment: Do you have any proxy settings configured on your IE browser?

Comment: Yes I'm using IE 11, It's works another function in the same document also...!

Comment: What do you append on url `xxxxxx` ?

Comment: Is it possible that IE is caching the AJAX response? `$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });` should stop anything from being cached.